# I keep getting some gaps in my text after scraping

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

anyone know how to eliminate these gaps in the scraped text because it makes it really hard to store them in csv file. The html has many gaps in the "username" class as shown in the picture below.

[image]

```
for i in range(0,2):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
    for username in soup1.find_all('div', class_="user-name"):
        print (username.get_text())
#    for time in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-ago"):
        
example = open('generalinfo.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(example,quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)        
wr.writerows(lists)    
example.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
username.get_text().strip()
```

to strip whitespace.